# Proper way to display information instead of UIAlertController

Tags: objective-c, macos, uialertcontroller

I have a certain `UIButton`, which sends an email to the user when pressed.
In iOS, I notify the user that a mail been sent to him via `UIAlertController`.

What is the proper way to do it in OS X? 
Alerts aren't meant for this case, so what are my options? 
Maybe what I'm looking for are Banners/notifications?